# Linux Ping not working and ssh cannot connect to linux

Tags: linux, centos, vmware, ip-address

I am new to linux and have been trying to connect ssh for a whole day but it is just not working:

I am using VMware to host virtual linux.

1. Initially I discovered that my virtual linux is not on the same ip as my Windows, where My Windows ip address is:192.168.1.79, so I changed my internet configuration of Linux to the following:

   ```
   TYPE=Ethernet
   PROXY_METHOD=none
   BROWSER_ONLY=no
   BOOTPROTO=static
   DEFROUTE=yes
   IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   IPV6INIT=yes
   IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
   IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
   IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
   NAME=ens33
   UUID=b5b31e0a-6326-4130-b7a3-8621377a9817
   DEVICE=ens33
   ONBOOT=yes
   DNS1=8.8.8.8
   IPADDR=192.168.1.188
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
   ```
2. I also changed form NAT to Bridged
3. After doing 1, where I changed the ip address of my linux to 192.168.1.188, I can successfully ping 192.168.1.188 on my Windows. But I cannot ping anything in linux.
4. I also notice that my setting of Adapter Vmnet8 is set to obtain an IP address automatically, and my current ip address for Vmnet8 is 192.168.238.1

Any help will be deeply appreciated!!! Have been working on this forever and could not get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to stick with standard setup and have your Linux VM obtain its IP address automatically via DHCP. That way, VMware (in NAT mode) or your router or DHCP server (in bridged mode) will take care of setting an IP address, netmask and default gateway that will allow the VM to communicate.

If for some reason you don't want to use automatic configuration, you have to choose a free IP address from the network you're connecting the VM to, and set the correct default gateway of that network. As you didn't share any information on your network setup I cannot help you with that.

Comment: May I ask what setup information you need?

Comment: As for automatic setup, I need static ip, is that doable through automatic setup?

Comment: Basic information for a network: gateway IP address and netmask, plus IP addresses of relevant systems - in this case, the address of the Windows machine which you did share already.

Comment: Static address: most routers or DHCP servers do have an option to assign a given machine a fixed address, but it depends on the router or DHCP server.

Comment: Ideally you should add such information to your question by editing it, so it can be referenced in the answer. While you're at it, also add what type of router you have, and mention if you have a separate DHCP server.

Comment: I have managed to let it autoconfigure, so thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But after I auto configure the IP address, I copied that IP address it assigns to me, then I set it as my static address. It works fine yesterday, but today my linux cannot connect to the Internet using that.

Comment: This goes now beyond what a Q&A site like Stack Exchange can do, and requires hands-on troubleshooting. Get someone knowledgeable to look at your system.